# how to keep the page from refreshing? jQuery Ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made a form where I submit new employee data to the database using jquery ajax and php. The data gets submitted and appears in the database, but how do I get it so the data will display on my page without the page refreshing?

I want the data to appear on the page without the page refreshing.

My problem: I can submit the data, but the page refreshes. If I make it so the page doesn't refresh, it won't submit the data.

```
    function createNewEmployee(){
require ('connection.php');
    $first = $_POST['first'];
    $last = $_POST['last'];
    $sin = $_POST['sin'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO employee (firstname, lastname, sin_, pass_) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$sin', '$pwd');";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}




  <form id="addform" action="addemployee.php" method="POST">
<p>Add New Employee:<p>
    <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last Name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sin" placeholder="SIN Number">
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="submitbtn">Add</button>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submitbtn").click(function() {
    var first = $("#name").val();
    var last = $("#last").val();
    var sin = $("#sin").val();
    var pwd = $("pwd").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {first:first,last:last,sin:sin,pwd:pwd},
      url: "addemployee.php",
      success: function(result) {
        $("#resultadd").html(response);
      }

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Are you sure you're using AJAX?

Comment: the way you insert data with ajax, same way just display it.

Comment: yeah sorry guys  forgot to upload my code, new to this site too lol

Comment: In ajax the page is not refresh,it shows the data in fields

Comment: You have a button type='submit' which causes the page to refresh when users click it.

Comment: instead of adding click handler on button add an onSubmit handler to the form. `$('#addForm').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // rest of your ajax code });`

Comment: Also, try to hash your password before inserting them into the database...

Comment: Why you are using ajax simply you can use php code to insert the data

Comment: @Tom because I'm using it to learn ajax and so the page doesn't refresh

Comment: @Enrico I changed the button type to button = "button" but now it won't even let me submit the data. nothing happens

Comment: apply return false;

Comment: Your PHP doesn’t return data to the frontend, so there’s nothing to display if the AJAX call succeeds.

Comment: @Hille I posted my code, but I was already as clear as i could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **return false;** after your ajax request to prevent the page from refreshing.

**Code Snippet**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitbtn").click(function() {
    var first = $("#name").val();
    var last = $("#last").val();
    var sin = $("#sin").val();
    var pwd = $("pwd").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {first:first,last:last,sin:sin,pwd:pwd},
      url: "addemployee.php",
      success: function(result) {
        $("#resultadd").html(response);
      }
```

`});

return false; }); });`

Comment: Check your console may be you have errors. return false works in every case.

Comment: the page doesn't refresh now but it won't submit the data anymore

Comment: Are you adding data using ajax? or using server side post method?

Comment: yeah adding data with ajax

Comment: Then you have error in your insertion. check your network for the status of your ajax request. it will help you solving the problem.

Comment: it lets me add data, but the page refreshes and i dont want that. if i use your code above, the page doesn't refresh, but no data is added to the database

Comment: you are calling this page **addemployee.php**, i think you are not calling the function **createNewEmployee** in that page.

Comment: just checked, it is being called

Comment: In form action also you called this page <form action="addemployee.php"> you can delete this action in form

Comment: change $_Request to $_POST also verify that your POST object has the data you sent from client side, further more read ajax docs for POST

Comment: @Tom just did that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     success: function() {
      location.reload();
window.location.href = "admin.php";
    }
```

Comment: would i change the "admin.php" to my file containing the php function?

Comment: admin.php is your first page

Comment: it must be a simple solution I am overlooking

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is a technology that was mainly developed to create more dynamic websites i.e. update parts of the webpage without a complete page refresh or server roundtrip.

You can read basics here. https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ajax_intro.asp

You`re using jQuery AJAX requests in JavaScript. So you can send and request data without blocking or refreshing the page. Also you are passing a success function with your AJAX request which will be executed asynchronously when the response arrives.

Your goal now is to create a PHP web service that sends a response body with your newly created employee and a correct http response code, indicating if the insertion was successful.

See the solutions stated here to get started in php web services:

[php web service example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242355/php-web-service-example)

and read about CRUD and REST like here:

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/execute-crud-in-mysql-php/ https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html

Use the response in the success callback function to update your employee collection and frontend.

Finally as stated in the comments already. Use something else then user data for your first attempts because user data is mostly very sensitive and needs advanced techniques.

To complete this here. Your current code will not update the whole page!Your goal is to use the response in a special part of the page without updating the wohle page. This is the concept of AJAX.

Also be careful with your variable names. This can't work because response is not defined:

```
success: function(result) {
    $("#resultadd").html(response);
}
```

Just for completion I'm adding code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitbtn").click(function() {
        var first = $("[name='first']").val();
        var last = $("[name='last']").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {first: first, last: last},
            url: "https://main.xfiddle.com/51da1682/addEmp1.php",
            success: function(result) {
                $("#resultadd").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});

<?php
    $dummyResponse->first = 'Foo';
    $dummyResponse->last = 'Bar';

    if (!$dummyResponse) {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo json_encode(mysqli_error());
    }

    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode($dummyResponse);
?>
```

This code is working for me, see this fiddle (valid for 2 days).
https://main.xfiddle.com/51da1682/addEmpApp4.php

Comment: i have already made the php crud but now im trying to make it so the page doesn't refresh so im trying to use ajax to fix that problem